# knockout foreach 2 columns

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I have been having some difficulty trying to format my data into 2 columns.

data

```
self.safeFloatDenominations = [
        { denomination: "£50", value: 350 },
        { denomination: "£20", value: 780 },
        { denomination: "£10", value: 370 },
        { denomination: "£5", value: 280 },
        { denomination: "£2", value: 398 },
        { denomination: "£1", value: 491 },
        { denomination: "50p", value: 57.5 },
        { denomination: "20p", value: 62.8 },
        { denomination: "10p", value: 576.20 },
        { denomination: "5p", value: 85.05 },
        { denomination: "2p", value: 100.04 },
        { denomination: "1p", value: 35.12 },
    ];
```

code

```
<div data-bind="foreach: safeFloatDenominations">
<input type="text" data-bind="value: value" />
<label data-bind="text: denomination"></label>
</div>
```

what I would like to get:

```
<div >
<input type="text" value="£50" />
<label>£50</label>

<input type="text" value="50p" />
<label>50p</label>
</div>
<div >
<input type="text" value="£20" />
<label>£50</label>

<input type="text" value="20p" />
<label>50p</label>
</div>
<div >
<input type="text" value="£10" />
<label>£50</label>

<input type="text" value="10p" />
<label>50p</label>
</div>
.......
```

does anyone know how I can split the foreach, so the data comes as desired?

**EDIT**

Just to clarify, does anyone know how I can split the list so the first half of the list data appears in column 1, and the second half of the list appears in column 2?

Answer (score 1):

Have you considered using something like bootstrap? You could place a class of `col-sm-6` on the outer `div`, which will place the rows in 2 columns. This method is preferred since this makes it easy to build a responsive layout by simply adding classes like `col-md-4`, which would place 3 columns side-by-side on medium sized screens. Similarly, `col-xs-12` would create just 1 column on phones.

Here's an example on [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cumy7g3c/).

**Edit:**

Ok, I see now, the columns need to be first record next to the middle record, the method above would place first record next to the second.

To achieve this behavior it's probably easiest to use [knockout-repeat](https://github.com/mbest/knockout-repeat).

Split the data into 2 arrays, the first half and the second half. (These could be computeds)

```
var half = self.safeFloatDenominations.length / 2;
self.sfd_part1 = self.safeFloatDenominations.slice(0, half);
self.sfd_part2 = self.safeFloatDenominations.slice(half);
```

Then in the HTML

```
<div data-bind="repeat: { count: sfd_part1.length }">
    <input type="text" data-bind="value: sfd_part1[$index].value" />
    <label data-bind="text: sfd_part1[$index].denomination"></label>

    <input type="text" data-bind="value: sfd_part2[$index].value" />
    <label data-bind="text: sfd_part2[$index].denomination"></label>
</div>
```

Here's a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/s1yqb1t3/3/).

Comment: this is good (actually I am using bootstrap), in that it lays out in 2 columns, but the complicated issue is that the first half of the list should be in the first column, and the second half should be in the second column.

Answer (score 1):

I'd agree with Matt's answer, and look at a different way of laying out the elements.

Having said that, what you want is doable.  Put a `computed` in front of your array that pairs up the data to be displayed in each column:

```js
var vm = function() {
  var self = this;
  
  self.safeFloatDenominations = [
        { denomination: "£50", value: 350 },
        { denomination: "£20", value: 780 },
        { denomination: "£10", value: 370 },
        { denomination: "£5", value: 280 },
        { denomination: "£2", value: 398 },
        { denomination: "£1", value: 491 },
        { denomination: "50p", value: 57.5 },
        { denomination: "20p", value: 62.8 },
        { denomination: "10p", value: 576.20 },
        { denomination: "5p", value: 85.05 },
        { denomination: "2p", value: 100.04 },
        { denomination: "1p", value: 35.12 },
    ];
  
  self.denominationPairs = ko.computed(function() {
    var ret = [];
    for (var x = 0; x < self.safeFloatDenominations.length; x+=2) {
      var pair = {};
      pair['left'] = self.safeFloatDenominations[x];
      if (x+1 < self.safeFloatDenominations.length)
        pair['right'] = self.safeFloatDenominations[x+1]
        ret.push(pair);
    }
    return ret;
  });
};

ko.applyBindings(new vm());
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.2.0/knockout-min.js"></script>

<div data-bind="foreach: denominationPairs ">
  <div>
    <input type="text" data-bind="value: left.value" />
    <label data-bind="text: left.denomination"></label>

    <!-- ko if: right != null -->
      <input type="text" data-bind="value: right.value" />
      <label data-bind="text: right.denomination"></label>
    <!-- /ko -->
  </div>
</div>
```

But really, try to work it with a different layout!